# To invoke Notepad++ from Git bash

Tags: git, bash, notepad++, git-bash

Trying to launch Notepad++ from Git Bash,so i did

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

then

```
> echo 'alias notepad++="C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

after this i restarted GitBash and tried to run  notepad++ ,but i am getting a warning and error message..

> WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or
>   ~/.profile.
>
> This looks like an incorrect setup. A ~/.bash_profile that loads
>   ~/.bashrc will be created for you.

if i run notepad++,its getting

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: What happens if you copy the portable executable to another location, without the `(x86)` in the path, and then use that as the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

OS: Windows 7 x64

Go to your `C:\Users\<your username>\`

Find `.gitconfig` file and open it with notepad or whatever text editor you like; add following lines to the end of the file

**Example**

```
[core]  
    editor = 'F:/Software/Notepad++/Notepad++Portable.exe'
```

you can also try this

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/TextPad 5/TextPad.exe' -m"
```

Obviously, replace the path with the path to your text editor and it should work.

Comment: editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin

Comment: replaced the above line with

Comment: editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' at the end of the file but still i am getting error message
bash:syntax error near unexpected token '(

Comment: What operating system are you using? @Smitha_nj

Comment: @Smitha_nj I just tried it on Windows 10 machine and it worked. I would try updating git to see if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use '\' or '\\'

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files \\\\(x86\\\\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
alias notepad="/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

Source: http://cruisebogedin.com/2014/01/make-notepad-default-editor-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

just tried to place Notepad++ folder in a different drive and with shell command
alias notepad++='d:/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
and this worked.